# How to prove the following identity: $\sum_{l = 0}^k \frac{1}{(l+1)!(k-l)!} = \sum_{l = 0}^k \frac{2^{k-l}}{(k+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

More broadly; I will need to prove

$\sum_{k_{n-1} = 0}^{k_n}...\sum_{k_2 = 0}^{k_3}\sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k_2} \frac{1}{(k_1+1)!(k_2-k_1)!(k_3-k_2)!...(k_n-k_{n-1})!} = \sum_{k_{n-1} = 0}^{k_n}...\sum_{k_2 = 0}^{k_3}\sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k_2} \frac{(n-1)!2^{k_2-k_1} 3^{k_3-k_2} 4^{k_4-k_3}...}{(k_n+1)!}$

I'm guessing similar arguments will apply for that more general case, but some intuition for either would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Recognize Cauchy products of absolutely convergent series.

Answer (score 2):

Case $n=2$. We have that
$$\sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k_2} \frac{1}{(k_1+1)!(k_2-k_1)!}=\frac{1}{(k_2+1)!}\sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k_2} \binom{k_2+1}{k_1+1}=\frac{2^{k_2+1}-1}{(k_2+1)!}=\sum_{k_1 = 0}^{k_2} \frac{2^{k_2-k_1}}{(k_2+1)!}.$$
Can you prove the general case?

Comment: Ah, I see, so I suppose in the more general case; we may rewrite the left side as a sum of  $\frac{1}{(k_n)!}\binom{k_n + 1}{k_{n-1}+1} {k_n + 1) \binom{k_{n-1} + 1}{k_{n-2}+1}...$ and we proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-induction based proof of the equality stated in the title

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac 1{(k+1)!(n-k)!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac {2^{n-k}}{(n+1)!}$$

Take the left-hand side and multiply the numerator and denominator by $(n+1)!$. This allows the sum to be rewritten in terms of the binomial coefficient

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\color{red}{\frac {(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}}\frac 1{(n+1)!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\color{red}{\binom {n+1}{k+1}}\frac 1{(n+1)!}$$

Next, recall the Hockey-stick identity

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\binom jk=\binom {n+1}{k+1}$$

Substituting for the red part of the expression gives us a double sum

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom {n+1}{k+1}\frac 1{(n+1)!}=\frac 1{(n+1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\binom jk$$

By expanding the double sum into its constituents, we can rewrite our nested sum by using the fact that

$$\binom nk=0\qquad\qquad n<k$$

Our double sum is equal to

$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}\left[\dbinom 00\right. & + & \dbinom 10 & + & \dbinom 20 & + & \cdots & + & \left.\dbinom n0\right] & +\\\left[\phantom{\dbinom 00}\right. & & \dbinom 11 & + & \dbinom 21 & + & \cdots & + & \left.\dbinom n1\right] & +\\\left[\phantom{\dbinom 00}\right. & & & & \dbinom 22 & + & \cdots & + & \left.\dbinom n2\right] & +\\ & & & & \vdots\\\left[\phantom{\dbinom 00}\right. & & & & & & & & \left.\dbinom nn\right] & +\end{array}$$

For any column $k$ starting from right to left, we have the sum of binomials down the column as

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom {n-k}j=2^{n-k}$$

Where the right-hand side comes naturally from the binomial theorem. Seeing that our $k$ must be $0\leq k\leq n$, our expression can be simplified into

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\binom jk=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom {n-k}j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n2^{n-k}$$

Moving the $(n+1)!$ term into our sum, we prove the identity stated in the title.

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac 1{(k+1)!(n-k)!}\color{blue}{=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac {2^{n-k}}{(n+1)!}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The top equality can be easily proved by induction. Since $\sum_{l=0}^{k+1}\frac{1}{(l+1)!(k+1-l)!}=\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{1}{(l+1)!(k-l)!}+\frac{1}{(k+2)!0!}$ and $\sum_{l=0}^{k+1}\frac{2^{k+1-l}}{(k+2)!} =\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{2^{k-l}}{(k+1)!}+\frac{2^{k+1-k-1}}{(k+2)!}$. The k+1 term is the same in both sums , therefore it is true for all  $ k\in \mathbb{N}$. I believe that the more general case can also be proved by induction on $k_{1},k_{2},..,k_{n}$ but the presentation is a lot more complicated!

Comment: OK ! I don't treat it as an inequality but as equality!

Comment: OK I found the error. It is just because we usually prove inequalities. Thanks a lot for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

**Title identity - Case $n=2$:**

The denominator of the right-hand side is independent of the index $l$. Multiplication with $(k+1)!$ shows we want to prove:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{l = 0}^k \frac{(k+1)!}{(l+1)!(k-l)!} = \sum_{l = 0}^k 2^{k-l}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Left-hand side of (1):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{l = 0}^k \frac{(k+1)!}{(l+1)!(k-l)!}}&=\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k+1}{l+1}=\sum_{l=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{l}\color{blue}{=2^{k+1}-1}\tag{2.1}
> \end{align*}
> Right-hand side of (1):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{l = 0}^k 2^{k-l}}&=\sum_{l=0}^k 2^l=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2-1}\color{blue}{=2^{k+1}-1}\tag{2.2}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we change the index to start with $l=1$ and apply the binomial theorem.
- In (2.2) we change the order of summation: $l\to k-l$ and use the *[geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula)*.

**Case $n=4$:**

Next we simplify the left-hand side of OPs claimed identity in the case $n=4$. This case provides enough information to derive a *general formula* from it for the case $n$. The validity can then be shown by a proof by induction. As in the title case $n=2$ we multiply both sides of OPs identity with $(k_n+1)!$ and we also divide by $(n-1)!$ using $n=4$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{3!}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{k_3=0}^{k_4}\sum_{k_2=0}^{k_3}\sum_{k_1=0}^{k_2}\frac{(k_4+1)!}{(k_1+1)!(k_4-k_3)!(k_3-k_2)!(k_2-k_1)!}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{k_3=0}^{k_4}\binom{k_4+1}{k_3+1}\sum_{k_2=0}^{k_3}\binom{k_3+1}{k_2+1}
> \sum_{k_1=0}^{k_2}\binom{k_2+1}{k_1+1}\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k_4+1}\binom{k_4+1}{k_3}\sum_{k_2=1}^{k_3+1}\binom{k_3+1}{k_2}
> \sum_{k_1=1}^{k_2+1}\binom{k_2+1}{k_1}\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k_4+1}\binom{k_4+1}{k_3}\sum_{k_2=1}^{k_3+1}\binom{k_3+1}{k_2}
> \left(2^{k_2+1}-1\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k_4+1}\binom{k_4+1}{k_3}\left(2\left(3^{k_3+1}-1\right)-\left(2^{k_3+1}-1\right)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{3!}\left(2\cdot3\left(4^{k_4+1}-1\right)-2\left(3^{k_4+1}-1\right)-\left(2^{k_4+1}-1\right)\right)}\tag{3.3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we expand numerator and denominator to conveniently use binomial coefficients.
- In (3.2) we shift the indices by one to be able to successively apply the binomial theorem in the following steps.

**General case:**

From (3.3) we derive a formula for general $n\geq 2$:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(n-1)!}&\sum_{k_{n-1}=0}^{k_n}\cdots\sum_{k_1=0}^{k_2}\frac{(k_n+1)!}{(k_1+1)!(k_{n}-k_{n-1})!\cdots!(k_2-k_1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left((n-1)!\left(n^{k_n+1}-1\right)-\sum_{j=1}j!\left((j+1)^{k_n+1}-1\right)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n^{k_n+1}-1-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}j!\left((j+1)^{k_n+1}-1\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{k_{n-1}=0}^{k_n}\cdots\sum_{k_1=0}^{k_2}2^{k_2-k_1}3^{k_3-k_2}
> \cdots n^{k_n-k_{n-1}}
> \end{align*}
> which can be used to prove OPs claim by induction.